# Four consecutive problems in Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

This is a doubt from Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis:

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> These are three consecutive exercises, and what I can see is : Calling
>
> A:Every infinite subset has a limit point.
>
> B:Space is compact
>
> C:Space is separable.
>
> D:Space has a countable base
>
> 23 says $C\implies D$ 24 says $A\implies C$, 25 says $B\implies C$ and 26 says $A\implies B$. I feel lost and confused in these implications, and I can't distinguish between them. Actually I can't figure out why we can't get rid of problem 24?

Comment: Exercise 26 mentions exercise 23, which says that a separable metric space has a countable base. So 24 says $A\implies C$, 23 says $C \implies B$, and 26 recaps the combination $A \implies B$ of 24 and 23.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I think, if 23 says something other than $C\implies B$ as I added in OP.  $\Bbb R$ is separable in usual topology but not compact.

Comment: Perhaps we called different things by the names of $A,B,C$. In my comment, $A$ is "limit point compact", $B$ is "has a countable base", $C$ is "separable". [Of course we're only considering metric spaces, the implications don't hold for arbitrary topological spaces.]

Comment: @DanielFischer, but then how do you denote exercise 26 as $A\implies B$ when you have no letter assigned to 'compact'? Also, by $\Bbb R$ with usual topology I meant reals with Eucledian metric.

Comment: I wrote that it recaps $A \implies B$, which is the first sentence of the hint. The task of the exercise is to prove that a limit point compact metric space is compact.

Comment: @DanielFischer I am sorry that I did not pay attention to word recap. I think this will be my las question:  Following your notation, and assigning $D$ to "compact"; In problem 26, Rudin says to use exercise 23 and 24, so I have to go this way: "Using 24, limit point compactness implies separable ($A\implies C$) and using 23, separable implies countable base ($C\implies B$)" And I am asked to show compact. So final implication path is "$A\implies C\implies B\implies D$".

Comment: @DanielFischer My question is: Can I deduce that because "$A\implies C\implies B\implies D$" holds, we get "$C\implies B\implies D$"? Or is this deduction some sort of violation of the fact that implication is not associative?

Comment: We don't have $B\implies D$, even for metric spaces. There are metric spaces that have a countable base but aren't compact. The proof hinted at in exercise 26 makes use of the fact that a limit point compact metric space has a countable base. That proof is to show $(A\land B) \implies D$. Exercises 23 and 24 are used to get $A\implies B$ and hence $A \implies (A\land B)$, which combined with the sketched proof of $(A\land B)\implies D$ gives the desired $A\implies D$ [and since we always have $D\implies A$, we get $A\iff D$ for metric spaces].

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! Now it is very clear.